# Why am I getting an "Unhashable type: 'list' " error?

Tags: python

I have this huge list ( `mylist` ) that contains strings like this:

```
>>> mylist[0]
'Akaka D HI -1 -1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1'
```

now, I want to take those 0, 1 and -1 and make a list with them, so I can make a list with the name at the first part of the string with the values of the list of 0, 1 and -1... so after some time I come up with this monstrosity

```
dictionary = {}
for x in range(len(mylist)-1):
    dictionary.update({mylist[x].split()[0],[]}),[mylist[0].split()[k] for k in range(3,len(mylist[0].split()))]})
```

But when I try that out in the commandline, I get this error:

```
>>> for x in range(len(mylist)-1):
...   dictionary.update({mylist[x].split()[0],[mylist[0].split()[k] for k in range(3,len(mylist[0].split()))]})
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
dictionary = {}
for x in mylist:
    p = x.find('1')
    if p > 0 and x[p-1] == '-': p -= 1
    dictionary[x[0:p].strip()] = x[p:].split()
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! That is pretty elegant

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
import re

st='Akaka D HI -1 -1 1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1'

dic={}
m=re.match(r'([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s(.*)',st)
if m:
    dic[m.group(1)]=m.group(2).split()
```

result:

```
{'Akaka D HI': ['-1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

```
import re

mydict = {}
for x in mylist:
    myname = re.search(r'^(.*?)(?= [-10])', x).group()
    myentry = re.findall(r'-*\d', x)
    mydict['myname'] = myentry
```

The first pattern starts at the beginning and matches any string until a space followed by a `-`, `1` or `0`, to capture the name. The second pattern matches any number, preceded by any number (zero included) of `-`, findall returns a list of all the pattern matches.